# Clean way to perform operations like sorting, filtering and pagination in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, rest

I wish to provide below options in the rest APIs, I am writing for a flask app.

- Filter

> GET /posts?title=json-server&author=typicode

- Paginate

> GET /posts?_page=7

- Sort

> GET /posts?_sort=views&_order=asc

- Slice

> GET /posts?_start=20&_end=30

- text search

> GET /posts?q=internet

Although these operations are easy to implement in python, I am confused about the clean way, like using a single wrapper or response builder, to implement them.

What should be the clean structure of implementing these operation?

Comment: I think I'd look at an extension like Flask-Restful https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html or Flask-Restless https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and just lean on the hard work of others-- it's a lot of work to roll your own for this kind of thing.